# Is this interpretation correct?

Tags: grammar

> China is now one of the world's major powers. Can't we say that without pride?

This construction...if taken alone without the context..it could mean two things?

> We can say that without pride.

or

> We can't say that without pride.

I think #2 is the correct one in the sentence.

Comment: Do you mean **which** is the correct one in the sentence?

Comment: Of your two alternatives, the bald surface meaning is unquestionably *We **can** say that without pride,* but that's not exactly the intended meaning. Effectively, the writer is arguing that *China is now one of the world's major powers* is a simple statement of fact. A fact which we should be able to reference without getting hung up over how people *feel* about this.

Comment: @FumbleFingers So from a purely grammatical point of view, the first one is correct. But the second one is contextually valid. Is that what you mean? So this construction could have either meaning depending on the context?

Comment: @user13505: There are no issues of "grammatical correctness" here (with/without negation, both versions are fine). The main difference is that negated *Can't we say that without pride?* is actually a ***rhetorical*** question. No answer is expected, because the speaker already knows the answer is ***Of course we can do that!*** (and expects the addressee to either already know this, or to agree with the speaker as soon as he hears it).

Answer (score 2):

"Can't we say that without pride?" is a figurative idiomatic expression that doesn't really have anything to do with what someone could or could not *say*.  It suggests a claim is factual, and not just based on personal or national pride.

For example, I might claim my country, "makes the best cheese in the world," but since "cheese quality" is difficult to quantify, it's more a statement of how proud I am of my country's dairy products than objective fact.

In contrast the writer in your example is saying that it's a *fact* China is a major power, and not *just* pride talking.

Comment: Is it possible to mean "we are proud to say that"?

Comment: @Rui: *Can't I say "No" without sounding dismissive?* In the cited context, the construction *Can't X happen without Y* is effectively a rhetorical way of emphatically asserting that X ***can*** happen without Y. Specifically, that China *can* claim to be one of the world's major powers - simply because it's a true statement, not because they feel proud about this. Just as it's possible for me to say Britain is the birthplace of the English language as a pure statement of fact, regardless of whether I take pride in it or not. Hell - even an *American* could say it.

Comment: I didn't realize that both version are grammatical then.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the idiom "Can't we do X?" means that we should do X, but that doing X is difficult or at least that people usually do not do X.

Like, "Can't we be friends?" We should be friends, but we aren't friends or we haven't been acting like friends. Perhaps we just met and so don't know each other well enough, or maybe we had an argument.

In this case, "Can't we say that without pride?", it's natural to be proud that one's nation is now a world power. It is surely tempting to be proud of it and to say that we are proud of it. But the writer believes that for some reason Chinese people should not be proud of it, or at least should not go around saying that they are proud of it.